# Array Manipulation C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to create a code that reads in an array, finds the smallest element in that array, and then subtracts that smallest element from all the other elements in the array and prints a new array with these elements.

The code I have written so far will not even compile. 
Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE(25);

void read_list(int a[], int&num_ele);
void print_array(const int a[], const int num_ele);
int find_min(const int a[], const int num_ele);
void array_subtract(int x, int&a[], int num_ele) ;



int main()
{
  int num_ele(0);
  int array[SIZE] ;

  read_list(array, num_ele);

  cout<<"Before list: ("<<num_ele<< " numbers): " <<endl;

  print_array(array, num_ele) ;

  min = find_min(array, num_ele) ;

  cout<<"The minimum value = "<<min<<endl;

  array_subtract(min ,array ,num_ele) ;

  cout<<"After list: ("<<num_ele<< " numbers): " <<endl;

  print_array(array, num_ele) ;


  return 0;
}


void read_list(int a[], int&num_ele)
{
  int x(0);

  cout<<"Enter positive numbers (ints) terminated 0: "<<endl;
  cin>>x;

  while(x!=0 && num_ele <= SIZE)
    {
      a[num_ele] = x ;
      num_ele++;
      cin >> x;
    }
}


void print_array(const int a[], const int num_ele)
{


  for(int i=0; i<num_ele; i++)
    {
      if(i<num_ele-1)
    {cout<<a[i]<<", "; }
      else
    {cout<<a[i]<<"."}
    }
}


int find_min(const int a[], const int num_ele)
{
  int x= a[0];
  for(int k=0; k<num_ele; k++)
    {
      if(a[k] < x)
    { x=a[k] ;}
    }

  return x ;
}

void array_subtract(int x, int&a[], int num_ele)
{
  for(int j=0; j<num_ele; j++)
    {
      a[j] = a[j]-x ;
    }
}
```

When I go to compile, at the line

```
  cout<<"The minimum value = "<<min<<endl;
```

I get about 100 lines of errors.

Is there some huge error in my code I am missing? Why would this happen? I would like to keep the code in the same format it is in (calling functions to get the final output).

Thanks

Comment: You haven't defined `min` as a variable.

Comment: `using namespace std;` and a (presumably) variable called `min`.. not a good idea.

Comment: You should go through each of the errors and fix them. You'll probably find that after you fix the first few, it will clear up many of the rest, because they're all side effects of a few common errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problems, after correcting these problems, at least you have not compile errors.

### i.

You're passing arrays wrong:

```
void array_subtract(int x, int&a[], int num_ele);
                           ^^^^^^^
```

Pass it like below (remove `&`)

```
void array_subtract(int x, int a[], int num_ele);
```

---

### ii.

You're using variable `min` without declaring it. Declare it like below:

```
int min;
```

---

### iii.

You've missed a semicolon `;` in function `print_array`:

```
cout<<a[i]<<".";
               ^
```

Comment: Awesome. I guess that was all I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You did not define variable min so the compiler reports errors when encounters statement

```
min = find_min(array, num_ele) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the compilation errors addressed by others...

Instead of using an array, use a vector (since logically you array is variably sized from 0-SIZE, and a vector is a variable sized array)...

```
vector<int> v;
```

Accept integer input until 0 is typed...

```
for(int n; cin >> n && n != 0;)
    v.push_back(n);
```

Find the min element...

```
auto min = min_element(begin(v), end(v));
```

Printing can be done a variety of ways...

```
cout << "Vector: [";
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
cout << "]\n";
```

Subtract the min from the elements...

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [min](int n){ return n-min; });
```

Try to use the C++ standard library when possible instead of hand rolling loops. It reduces the potential for bugs, and is often clearer (but not always... for example that print I posted above doesn't exactly read intuitively IMO)